# Android - Cannot see Options Menu when extends SherlockFragmentActivty

Tags: android

![Layout Look like this][1]

[1]strong text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIsz8.png

I am trying to create a menu, but I am unable to see the menu.i am able to see menu in fragments properly. but cannot see in the sherlockfragmentactivity that is my main frame for fragment.

when i click on menu they doesn't take any action.

**menu code**

```
<group android:id="@+id/dashbardmenu">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:title="ABC">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:title="Setting">
    </item>
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/fragmentmenu" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/form"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Form">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/resetform"
        android:title="Reset Form">
    </item>
</group>
```

im using visibility & invisibility for particular file.

**java code**
1st way

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionaMenu(Menu menu ){
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity, menu);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.fragmentmenu, false);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

2nd way

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionaMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater ){

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity, menu);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.fragmentmenu, false);

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    super.onOptionsItemSelected((MenuItem)item);
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.abc:
        //Some action
    case R.id.setting:
        //Some action

    default:
        return false;
    }
}

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    super.onOptionsItemSelected((MenuItem)item);
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.abc:
        //Some action
    case R.id.setting:
        //Some action

    default:
        return true;
    }
}
```

Where is my Mistake Anyone help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you call this?

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Also you have a typo - method name is **onCreateOptionsMenu** but you have twice **onCreateOptionaMenu**

Comment: @ Greg  Its an example i'm using any one at a time.. this is the two different way that i will try but no one will work.

Comment: method name is onCreateOptionsMenu but you have twice onCreateOptionaMenu... See the typo?

Comment: method name onCreateOptionsMenu change with onCreateOptionsMenu... ITs Work Fine Thank u @Greg.. :)